Conflicting dependencies, duplicate classes and version numbers in implementing Google AdMob in Android Studio
I need to know the magic configuration for the gradle file to actually work and run my app again.
I know that this is happening because I am adding AdMob ads!
I have gotten many different types of errors just be changing the dependency versions on the following gradle information: please note: Am using old version of Android Studio: 4.1.3

buildtoolsversion: seems like the latest I can use is 30.0.3.
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'  I have used: 1.11.0(latest) and 1.4.0
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'  I have used: 23.1.0 , 22.4.0 , 22.3.0 , 22.5.0 . I would rather use 22.3.0 since other projects of mine have used it!
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')  I have used 32.5.0

Now, by running the app with version 22.10 for item 3 above AND version 26.7.0 for item 4 above. I get the following error:  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio
Somehow, I read in an article that by switching the order of the dependencies gradle can get rid of the duplicate class problem. Which seems like it did for me!
By running the app with version 22.10 for item 3 above AND version 26.7.0 for item 4 BUT declaring the play-services-ads dependency AFTER the firebase-bom dependency I get the error:
AAPT: error: resource xml/gma_ad_services_config (aka com.noodles.numbercruncher:xml/gma_ad_services_config) not found.
I tried to get rid of the error above by doing this which I read in another Stack Overflow post:
I added this to my mainactivity manifest:
 <meta-data
        android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
        android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />

Now, I believe that since I used firebase integration it is conflicting with Google Admob api classes! Is there a way to tell gradle to get rid of duplicate classes?
But, that did not resolve anything. Why does Google make life complicated for developers! Why we have to keep track of all this libraries and dependencies and conflicting version numbers. I hope that the new Android Studio has enough brain power to solve this type of problems in a second!
Here is my gradle file inside my Android Studio version 4.1.3:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
// compileSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 33

//  buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
 // buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "not typed in this sample of the gradle file"
    minSdkVersion 24
    //targetSdkVersion 30
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 73
    versionName '2.03'
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

// Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
// language features (either in its source code or
// through dependencies).

compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


dynamicFeatures = [":camerafeature"]


}

repositories{
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
//testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'//care this used to read 4.+ remember.. but then lint 
 complained!
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
// androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0' here_253 this 
 was used before!!

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'


api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
implementation 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8'

implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.3'

api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'//this was 1.2.0

implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01'

api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

//used for desugaring purposes. .to make new apis of java8 available in older java version devices
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'

def billing_version = "7.0.0"
 // def billing_version = "7.0.0"

implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3' //this used to be 1.10.0

implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android")

// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0') //this one was used before
// implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')

// Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
// When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'




}


List item

